# How come my local website is not using the last edit of my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, iis

How come my local website is not using the last edit of my JavaScript code? 
I have tried it in FireFox and GoogleChrome with the same result.  When I added alert(id), 
it did not show up after I refreshed the page.   How can I see the results immediately?

**Additional Information:**
OS :Window XP
IIS 5.1

This is the picture using FireBug to retrace localhost using old JavaScript code, on right side is Dreamweaver New Code 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried holding shift while clicking refresh, this will prevent it from loading from cache. Happens occasionally.

---

If this is happening in both browsers, you must not be saving your new code to the same file, browsers don't share cache's.

Comment: Let's me Try Shift + refresh

Answer (score 1):

This is because some elements (as js scripts) are cached in the browser history.

A possible workaround for development use, is to concatenate a timestamp to the script name, so it will always be refreshed, as the name changes on every page load.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://my.site.net/res/myScript.js?123456789"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome you can disable the cache from the Developer Tools (ctrl + shift + i). I think there are also some extensions available. (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap?hl=en)